# Is There a Way to Ignore Bad Certificate When Using RCurl getURL()

Tags: r, rcurl

Just started using RCurl to read XML data from URL on HTTPS and I have been getting errors complaining about certification, so I was wondering if anyone knows a way to ignore certification and have some examples. I know ignoring certification can be done in java, python and C#, just not sure how it is done in R with RCurl.

Answer (score 1):

You can the the `ssl.verifypeer` option:

```
options(RCurlOptions = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE))
```

but as all the sites warn you this should be the last resort since you will be throwing all the security SSL gives you out of the window.